# Нужна запятая перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*Он молча выслушал историю о летающих журавлях(,) и с заинтересованным, живым лицом прочитал в книге страницу, полную невообразимых рисунков.*

Если ставится - почему? Если нет, то тоже почему?

И если поменять предложение на такое:

*Он выслушал историю и прочитал страницу.*

То тут не ставится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь однородные члены предложения (сказуемые "выслушал" и "прочитал") соединены одиночным союзом "и". В таких случаях запятая **не** ставится:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

Имеющееся здесь обстоятельство образа действия при втором сказуемом (с заинтересованным, живым лицом) этого не меняет. Исключением в подобных случаях бывает (см. там же) присоединительное значение союза "и" ("при этом", "вследствие этого" и т. п.), но в данном примере таковое трудно усмотреть.

Answer (score 3):

Не вижу причин постановки запятой ни в первом, ни во втором случае: и там и там однородные сказуемые в простом предложении -  он выслушал и  прочитал.

Comment: А из-за того, что  здесь есть причастие "летающих" - всё равно не ставится?

Comment: Выслушал историю(какую?) о журавлях (каких?) летающих - одиночное причастие стоит перед определяемым словом - запятой нет. Была бы запятая, если б было определение, выраженное причастным оборотом или одиночными прилагательными, и стояло бы оно после опред. слова: он выслушал историю о журавлях, летающих высоко в небе, и прочитал ...